# Which android template should I use to create an android background activity?

Tags: android, eclipse-juno

Sorry, but I am new to android development. I am trying to create an app that will run in the background and check for incoming SMS messages and show a pop up with the content of the message. I don't know which android template to use for such an app. I'm using eclipse juno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at `Service`s to do background stuff and issue notifications.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use a BroadcastReceiver

public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

if (extras == null)
return ;

Object[] dataArr = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
```

for (Object data: dataArr) {
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) data);

```
        String body = sms.getMessageBody();
        String sender = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
```

}
}

and register your broadcastReceiver in your manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".sms.SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true" > 
<intent-filter > 
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Hope this help you.